# Specify custom value to build S3 Key in Zapier integration Gmail to S3

Tags: amazon-s3, gmail, integration, zapier

I'm creating a Zapier integration from Gmail to S3. In 'Upload File in Amazon S3' part under the 'Customize Upload File' section, I want to be able to create the Key as 
(YYYY-MM)/test/(filename) 
e.g.
2020-03/test/myfile.csv. 
I want to get (YYYY-MM) from the email. I can see the option of date under 'insert a field' but it is the full date including time 
e.g. Wed, 4 Mar 2020 09:30:43 +0000
 so the Key becomes: 
 'Wed, 4 Mar 2020 09:30:43 +0000/test/myfile.csv'. 
Is there a way to get the year and month from date and specify it in the Key?

Answer (score 0):

I implemented it executing Zapier code in between Gmail and S3. So it was:
Gmail -> Zapier Code (Python) -> S3
The date from Gmail became input to the code. Converted it to string YYYY-MM, which became output and could now be used in S3 to form the desired Key.